# How to remove lubuntu from dual boot xubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, lubuntu

Xubuntu 16.04 and Lubuntu 15.1 dual boot on EEE-PC 1000HE.

Goal: Owner wants Lubuntu removed and run Xubuntu.

1. What are the the steps to remove and reclaim the diskspace for Xubuntu? Maybe it is as simple as removing the Lubuntu partition?
2. How to remove the option to boot Lubuntu and always boot Xubuntu
3. Are there any other considerations (tasks) or questions missing required to  achieve the goal?

Hopefully, I am asking the right questions here: I am open to modifying any question: before banishing this question please help with suggestions \ edit to make it better so that it serves the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete the Lubuntu partition and then add that space to the partition with Xubuntu on it.  Because there is always a chance of losing data, please back up any data that you cannot live with out before you start this procedure.  All of this can be done with GParted.  If you have not installed it, you can either install it from the repositories or boot from any install disk (It will be on there.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an option when installing Xubuntu that allows you to replace the current working OS, but not affect the files in the laptop.